# How to load a bootstrap js file in my case?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, gruntjs, bower

I have a question regarding loading the dependencies using Bower.

I have bower.json like

```
{
  "name": "My project",
  "version": "0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.2.0",  
    "angular-bowser": "~0.0.1"
  }
}

//I want to add alert.js dependency
```

I was hoping to add a custom bootstrap JS file that is only for alert. I am not sure how to add the custom file since I can't run `bower install` to install the custom file.

Any tips? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You add `bootstrap` as a Bower dependency. Then in whatever *other* tool you're using to either generate `<script>` tags or generate a single concatenated JS file, you add Bootstrap's `alert.js` (and any other Bootstrap jQuery plugins that Alert depends on) to the list of required JS files.

Speaking more generally, Bower is an pretty minimalistic package manager, to the point that it is arguably not very useful, as it provides relatively little metadata and leaves many issues to instead be dealt with by other tools or by the user manually. Hence, what you're asking for here goes beyond the realm of Bower itself.